# keybindings for a single character in emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I would like to use "Ctrl+'" to replace "\" (i.e., the backslash key). How should I do that? Originally I did it by kbd macro, but it is still different. For example, for the package smartparens, if one types "\{", a "\}" will be automatically typed. However, keyboard macro "ctrl+'"+"{" is not the same as "\{" for this case.

So I am just wondering if there are other ways achieving this? Some global keybinding tool (works for the whole X system) is also ok. But so far I cannot find one that can do such keybinding (two keys for one key).

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want one of the translastion maps described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html

Comment: I am sorry. I know very little about elisp, so I cannot understand the webpage... Are there other easier examples illustrating this? Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the translation map suggested by @Barmar you may wish to consider using something like `(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") "\\")`.  Two back-slashes equals just one when it gets inserted into the buffer.

Comment: @lawlist I just did what you suggested; unfortunately, for smartparens this is still not the same as "\{".

Comment: I found that KDE "custom shortcuts" allows one to define global keybinding that satisfies my needs. But other approaches directly in Emacs are definitely welcome.